# Find two sets where a general quadratic is injective

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$.

Assume $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. We have then

\begin{gather*}
a\left(x_1+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} = a\left(x_2+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} \iff\\
\left(x_1+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 = \left(x_2+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 \iff\\
x_1+\frac{b}{2a} = x_2+\frac{b}{2a} \vee x_1+\frac{b}{2a} = -x_2-\frac{b}{2a}\iff\\
x_1 = x_2\vee x_1 = -x_2-\frac{b}{a}
\end{gather*}

so $f$ is not injective.

How would I partition $\mathbb{R}$ into two intervals where $f$ is injective using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic is injective on the intervals $(-\infty, -b/2a]$ and $[-b/2a,\infty)$ as well as any interval properly contained in one of those. There are other regions, though not other intervals.

To see why, examine the quadratic equation. $f(x)=k$ has solutions exactly where $ax^2+bx+(c-k)$ has roots. You need to capture either the $+$ or the $-$ but not both for the function to be injective, which means staying on one side of $-b/2a$.

Comment: @user159517 the empty interval is properly contained in these intervals. I'm not saying these two are the only ones, I'm saying these two and all of their proper subintervals are

Comment: I know this to be true but I would quite like an argument as to why those two intervals do the job.

Comment: @Neutronic I said why. Because by the quadratic equation the interval can only contain numbers on one side of $-b/2a$

Comment: How does this follow from the quadratic equation?

Comment: @Neutronic  Please point to the words in my second proof that doesn't make sense to you, and why you think it's not true/might not be true.